# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getPassword') error in vs code

Tags: django

I am getting this annoying error in vs code in the bottom right. It shows when i try to connect vs code with my local mysql server. Any solutions to this?
[This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cj9p.png)

I properly checked mysql and made sure that all the information of the database is correct in my project.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

same thing happened to me after this new update of vs code, i cant view my database but it is still accessing so

Comment: Yes, I can access the database too but visualizing the database in vs code is helpful

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem and I got VS Code installed in snap, so I reverted the VS Code version with "**snap revert code**" command, and now MySQL extension works well again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so I re-install the VSCode version before, and now MySQL extension works again!